# Overlapping kubelet's container_memory_rss metrics from OOMKilled pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubelet

I'm investigating an OOM kill of one of services in my kubernetes cluster.

One of the first things I did was to look at a grafana plot of memory usage of the pod that was killed and to my surprise I saw a big spike in memory usage just around the OOM happened.
However, the pod itself wasn't running any computations at that time so such a spike was very confusing (the pod itself has a memory leak which made it slowly reach memory limit but the spike was not part of it).

I've looked closer into the spike using Prometheus and I've learnt that for a short moment, when old pod is being replaced by a new one, `kubelet` reports metrics from both pods, which then due to `sum by (container)` used in grafana plot shows a spike.

Without aggregation: (`container_memory_rss{pod="XXX", container!="POD", container!=""}`)
[image: container_memory_rss{pod="XXX", container!="POD", container!=""}]

With aggregation: (`sum by(container) (container_memory_rss{pod="XXX", container!="POD", container!=""})`)
[image: sum by(container) (container_memory_rss{pod="XXX", container!="POD", container!=""})]

I was wondering if the overlap can be avoided somehow and whether it stems from some incorrect configuration on my side or either it's a behaviour of `kubelet` or `prometheus` that cannot be avoided.

Thanks!